# KendoUI Datasource Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-ui

I wrote two functions,assume that one of them get us list of all notifications and one of them get new notification, i wrote a script which call first method and get list of all notifications in Json format, and write another script which call second method every 8 second, and get us new notifications in Json format too. i show these notifacations in a KendoUI Datasource. so i have two datasource for just one KendoUI Datasource component, i want to add two data source in  one datasource, is there any way to do this?

EDIT: This is my code

```
 <script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
             
          <tr>

            <td>#= ID #</td>
            <td>#= TITLE #</td>
            <td>#= DESC #</td>
               
           </tr>
  </script>
```

My first script which get us list of all notification :

```
       var datas = function () {

                        var objects = [];
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "./WebForm1.aspx/GetNoti",
                            data: {},
                            async: false,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success:
                                function (response) {

                                    for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {

                                        objects.push({ 'ID': response.d[i].ID, 'TITLE': response.d[i].TITLE, 'DESC': response.d[i].DESC });

                                    }
                                },

                        });
                        return objects;
                    };




                    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        data: datas(),
                        change: function () {
                            $("#movies tbody").html(kendo.render(template, this.view()));
                        }
                    });

                   dataSource.read();
```

and this is my seccond script which call method that give us new notifications every 8 sec:

```
     $("#go").click(function () {
                        setInterval(
                            function () { test2();}, 8000);
                    });

        var p = function () {
                        var objects = [];
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "./WebForm1.aspx/GetUnCheckNotification",
                            data: {},
                            async: false,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success:
                                function (response) {

                                    for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {

                                        objects.push({ 'ID': response.d[i].ID, 'TITLE': response.d[i].TITLE, 'DESC': response.d[i].DESC });

                                    }
                                },

                        });
                        return objects;

                    };

          function test2() {

                        var dataSource2 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            data: p(),
                            change: function () {
                                $("#movies tbody").html(kendo.render(template, this.view()));
                            }

                        });
                        dataSource2.read();

                    }
```

Now i want some thing like this :

> dataSource = dataSource + dataSource2
>
> dataSource.read();

Is there anyway?

Comment: can you please provide some code so that we can check your dataSource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON format cab be a nested structure. Define a view model and then use it.

```
public class Report
{
    public int Id {set; get;}
    public string Title {set; get;}
    public string Desc {set; get;}
}

public class MyReportViewModel
{
  public List<Report> NewNotifications {set;get;}
  public List<Report> AllNotifications {set;get;}
}
```

- Then serialize this `new MyReportViewModel { ... }` using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library (server side).
- On the client side, you can use the returned JSON format [as usual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json).

Comment: What you're mean is i dont need two script one for AllNotifications and another for NewNotifications ? what about my method ? can you explain me more about this please?

Comment: Yes, you can combine them together as a view model + To signal users about the new changes from server, it's better to use `SignalR` and not just querying the server every 8 seconds. SignalR is much more efficient for these kinds for tasks.

Comment: Thanks,,i confuse abit:( about my method  i write two method with StoredProcedure one of them give use All notification and the other one is new notification with where condition uncheck=true, i write webmethod method, i should make change on these methods and SP or not??

Comment: no. you have 2 properties here in `MyReportViewModel`. create a new instance of it and return it as a json. also you can apply `caching` for the all rows parts as well (server side).

Comment: I should read notification from my DataBase! how can i can do it?? sorry, I really confused

Comment: read them from the database (as before) and then assign these values to the properties of the view model. you wanted a single data source for your client side grid. this view model gives you that. it's a single nested object.

Comment: In this way if i wrote a script that call the method ( which Serialize the 'new MyReportViewModel { ... }') every 8sec, it's call two method which assign to two properties every 8sec, so it gives us both of AllNotification and NewNotification , but i want a way which the first time give us AllNotification(so just once time call the method which assign to AllNotifications property) and every 8 sec give us NewNotification(so it call just the method which assign to NewNotifications property every 8sec).. are u understand what i mean?

Comment: Try caching (Caching API, Using the Cache Object) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Never tried anything like this. But when I was looking for your answer, I found this link at Telerik Forums.

[**Two Data Sources, One Grid**](http://www.telerik.com/forums/two-data-sources-one-grid)

This might help.! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answering.. if its not a good way.. may you advice me a better wat please?

Comment: It's not a Grid. Its a DataSource component